# Excel - Filtering for multiple dates / #s within one cell

Tags: excel, filtering, vba

I have downloaded a data table from a sharepoint list website into a excel file and have filtered for the keyword 'Contract' which narrowed down my results from 1000 rows to approx 180 rows.

I am tasked with determining the # of contractors Between date X and Y.

The filters I would normally use are:

```
Employment Type = Contract
Contract Start Date >= 10/01/2017
contract End Date <= 05/31/2018
```

The issue I am having is all this data is contained within 1 cell and there are two variations of spelling for 'Contract' (Contract and Contact).. so I also have to factor this is.

Here is a small snippet from 1 of the cells:

```
"Position":"Account Services Agent","Manager Name":"xxxx","Manager Phone":"43524325","Employment Type":"Contract","Contact Start Date":"01/08/2018","Contact End Date":"03/30/2018","Beeline Request ID number":"67160"},{"ID":"1111","Name":"xxxx ","Position":"Account Services Agent","Manager Name":"xxxx ","Manager Phone":"4444444","Employment Type":"Contract","Contact Start Date":"01/08/2018","Contact End Date":"03/30/2018","Beeline Request ID number":"67160"},{"ID":"333333","Name":"xxxx ","Position":"Account Services Agent","Manager Name":"xxxxx ","Manager Phone":"44444","Employment Type":"Contract","Contact Start Date":"01/08/2018","Contact End Date":"03/30/2018"
```

I need to somehow determine how many contractors there are that meet my date range criteria

Any ideas/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Split the data into individual cells. If the dates are to be used as `>=` and `<=` criteria, that's just plain bad worksheet design.

Comment: That looks like some sort of bastardized json formatting. Perhaps you can build a better data matrix with json tools.